# How to export Python secret password to CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create x amount of passwords using Python's Secrets module then export them out to a new CSV file. I can create the passwords and print them on screen but when I write to a CSV, the characters are parsed out by comma. (Apologies for code not being displayed as properly blocked out)

Code:

```
import secrets
import string
import csv

need = input("Number of passwords:")
need = int(need)
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

with open('password.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    passwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for n in range(need):
        password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(10))
        print(password)
        passwriter.writerow(password)
```

Currently I get this output which is not what I want:

[image: screenshot]

I want the output to look like:
[image]

Comment: What should the resulting CSV file look like? (Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59754799/edit) the question.)

Comment: In case you are not aware, CSV means *comma-separated*. So it seems you don't actually want a CSV file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interpreting your `string` as a list of values, turn it into a tuple of one value like this:

```py
passwriter.writerow((password,))
```